# How to decide if an array is a permutation of 1-N in O(log N)?

Tags: c++, permutation

A sequence of length n is called a permutation if it contains all integers from 1 to n exactly once.

Can you tell whether an array is a permutation in O(log N)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve] of *your own* attempt and [edit] your question to show it, together with a description of the problems you have with it. And lastly please actually as a question inside your question (and have the title be a short summary of the question/problem).

Comment: Did you mean "How to tell **if** an array **is** a permutation" ?

Comment: My first thougt was that it should be hard to beat O(N) considering that you have to watch at least each array element once. But, maybe, I'm seeing this from wrong angle. I'm curious how this will end. ;-)

Comment: @DanielChristianMandolang: I edited your question body to include the title, which has the actual question. If this is not what you meant, please edit yourself and clarify.

Comment: are you sure about the `O(log N)` ? It would make a nice exercise if it was asking for `O(N log N)` because then you could try different things just to realize that sorting is all you need, but checking a property of N numbers in less than `O(N)` seems impossible

Comment: Or do you talk about quantum computing? Then O(log N) could be about right ...

Comment: Or should O(log N) be the average runtime for random entries (any int or ints between 1..n)? Then the algorithm could break early in many cases. Then the task would involve to theoretically show that the average runtime is O(log N) for a certain distribution of inputs.

Answer (score 5):

You mean to tell, whether an array contains a permutation?
O(log N) is not enough: You need O(N) to read all elements.
O(N*log N) would be enough to sort the array, then it is trivial to tell whether it is a permutation in O(N).

You could update a histogram during each write into the array and also update a counter, how many histogram entries are exactly 1. This would cost O(1) for each update and O(1) for the actual test.

```
constexpr int N = 1000;
std::array<int, N> arr = {};      // zero-init
std::array<int, N + 1> hist = {}; // zero-init, we ignore element 0 and use elements 1..N
int counter = 0;

// writes  arr[i] = newv  in O(1)
void write(int i, int newv) {
    if(i < 0 || i > N-1)          // invalid index
        return;

    const int oldv = arr[i];      // read previous array entry

    if(oldv > 0 && oldv <= N) {   // decrease histogram
        if(hist[oldv] == 1)
            --counter;
        --hist[oldv];
        if(hist[oldv] == 1)
            ++counter;
    }

    arr[i] = newv;                // set array

    if(newv > 0 && newv <= N) {   // increase histogram
        if(hist[newv] == 1)
            --counter;
        ++hist[newv];
        if(hist[newv] == 1)
            ++counter;
    }
}

// tests for permutation in O(1)
bool testPermutation() {
    return counter == N;
}
```

Comment: I would consider your histogram approach O(N).

Comment: O(N) if you do it afterwards, that's right, O(1) if you do it during each write.

Comment: Starting off with the assumption that the array is a permutation, you can even sort it in linear time, since you just need to swap each element to its target location. As soon as you find an out-of-bounds element or you want to swap an element with an equal element, you know it wasn't a permutation.

Comment: `O(1)` for the actual test? I dont understand what the histogram changes about the situation, you still need to check each of the `N` bins of the histogram which makes it the same `O(N)` as before

Comment: The task is to do it in O(log N). So you need an enhanced array, which does not have to look at each element to test for containing a permutation. The counter, how many histogram bins are 1, is updated with each write operation. The actual test just reads the counter and compares it with N.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot tell if an array is a permutation without looking at each entry of the array, thus you need at least `n` steps in your algorithm.

A simple linear-time solution is to attempt to compute the inverse permutation (assuming 0-based indexing):

```
std::vector<int> inverse(n, -1);

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (array[i] < 0 || array[i] >= n || inverse[array[i]] != -1) {
        break; // not a permutation!
    }
    inverse[array[i]] = i;
}
```